# Specifying a Character Encoding for Javascript

Tags: javascript, character-encoding, internationalization, uppercase, turkish

I am trying to convert a string into uppercase using a specific character encoding, but it fails.

When I convert istanbul, it converts it into ISTANBUL. However, uppercase "i" is "İ" in Turkish. Is there any solution to this?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fgZZp/

Thanks in advance,

Comment: See also possible duplicate: **[Turkish case conversion in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1850232/turkish-case-conversion-in-javascript)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To some degree - the JavaScript String class does have a `toLocaleUpperCase` method, but the locale used is always the user's locale. You can't arbitrarily choose a locale for it to use.

(Nitpick: What you're asking about is a locale issue, not character encoding. Character encoding only has to do with what bits are used to represent a given character; it doesn't generally affect how operations on those characters should behave.)

Comment: Thanks really. Though, I will probably use the function in the other link that hippietrail has posted. It needs to be persistent across the browsers.