# JavaScript: Culture-independent case-insensitive string comparison

Tags: javascript, string-comparison, culture

If this exact question has been asked before, please point me to the relevant question.

tl;dr: How does one compare two strings in JavaScript while ignoring casing according to **English** rules?

My code analyzes and compares data from two different sources, each with different opinions about whether keywords should be upper or lower case, meaning that a case-insensitive comparison is required. However, I don't want the system to break if used in other cultures (such as Turkey and its notorious problems with the letter I).

Does JavaScript have any way of doing a culture-independent (read: English) case-insensitive string comparison?

Comment: You mean, you want to compare only A-Z/a-z case-insensitive and everything else case-sensitive? Why do you call "according to English rules" "culture-independent"?

Comment: Sounds theoretically impossible. How do you want to compare, say, the German ß in a "culture-independent" case-insensitive manner? Or both French, in which the capital versions of accented letters lose their accents, and languages in which they don't. The whole concept of case is language dependent, I think.

Comment: @Bergi @RemcoGerlich: Perhaps my choice of terminology was bad. By "culture-independent", I'm not making a statement about English being a "neutral" culture. Instead, what I request is a way to compare two strings in a case-insensitive manner in a way that is **consistent between computers of different locales**. For example, I want to ensure that `EXIT` is considered equal to `exit` on every computer in the world, including ones set to Turkish where the capitalization rules for the letter I are different.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> How does one compare two strings in JavaScript without breaking if used in other cultures (such as Turkey and its notorious problems with the letter I)? Does JavaScript have any way of doing a culture-independent case-insensitive string comparison?

Yes, by simply using the [standard `.toLowerCase` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) which is *not affected* by locale settings. `a.toLowerCase() == b.toLowerCase()` is perfectly fine. The [spec](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.16) even mandates:

> *The result must be derived according to the case mappings in the Unicode character database*

This definitely is consistent across all systems regardless of their settings.

---

For respecting the current locale, you would use [`.toLocaleLowerCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLocaleLowerCase) explicitly. MDN states:

> In most cases, this will produce the same result as toLowerCase(), but for some locales, such as Turkish, whose case mappings do not follow the default case mappings in Unicode, there may be a different result.

However, [relying on locales does not seem to work well](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1850232/1048572)…

Comment: Its kind of sad to see that this is the most voted answer. Do JavaScript developers really have no sense of programming? Never heard of case-insensitive comparison? So sad to see that the correct answers are the ones with the lowest votes and on most question, there's not even a single correct answer in the first place. Case-Insensitive Comparision been a thing in other languages for many decades already, why people still even ever consider upper or lower case as a solution?

Comment: @Tseng No need to be derogatory. Sure I know of case-insensitive comparisons, but JS provides no such operator. So what's wrong with using `toLowerCase()`? What would you deem the correct answer?

Comment: Well look at the answer below. Most major browser have been supporting it fully since mit/late 2013. I literally went through 10 questions and 30 answers all with the same wrong suggestions. What is wrong in the JavaScript world?

Comment: @Tseng You mean `String.prototype.localeCompare`? OP asked for a culture-**independent** comparison, not one that uses the current browser language. Also `{ sensitivity: "base" }` isn't exactly case-insensitive - it may ignore casing but also ignores the actual letter itself.

Comment: @Bregi Dude, that's exactly what culture independent means!!!! It means if you have "Fuß" and "Fuss" it compares to equal and NOT to different values (or sorting). That's why toUpperCase and toLowerCase is COMPLETELY Wrong approach. The opposite is culture dependent where "Fuss" and "Fuß" do not means equal or "Für" and "Fur". Other terminology for that is "Invariant" and "Ordeal".

Comment: @Tseng Nope. Consider `'a'.localeCompare('ä', undefined, { sensitivity: 'base' })` - the result of that is dependent on the culture (locale), it'll return 0 with German and -1 with Swedish browser settings. *That* is exactly the dependency that the OP is trying to avoid.

Comment: That's what you can use the second parameter for to change it to a language most suitable for your websites content. Or use `und` for undetermined.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `localeCompare` but be aware that it is implemented differently between browsers. What seems to work in Chrome/Firefox/IE11 is:

```
first.localeCompare("First", navigator.language, { sensitivity: "base" }) === 0
```

```js
var console = function() {
    var log = function(message) {
      strMessage = "<p>" + message + "</p>";
      $("#console").append(strMessage);
    };
    
    return {
        log: log
    };
}()

var first = "first";
var result = first.localeCompare("First", navigator.language, { sensitivity: "base" }) === 0;
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="console">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

In theory there is a method for that: [String.localCompare()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare).

The problem is that it's not implemented correctly by most browsers.

You might have more luck using [String.toLocaleLowerCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLocaleLowerCase).

Example:

```
if ("Äpfel".toLocaleLowerCase() == "äpfel".toLocaleLowerCase()) alert("Case Insensitive Match")
```

Be aware that following will not match (because ä and a are different characters):

```
if ("Äpfel".toLocaleLowerCase() == "apfel".toLocaleLowerCase()) alert("Case Insensitive Match")
```

Comment: This answer is from 2014, but as of 2024, all major browsers have supported the ES6 `Intl` features for quite some time now, so don't be afraid to use `localeCompare()` - plus it's also much faster than using `toLowerCase` or `toLocaleLowerCase` because those functions create new string instances, which is more expensive than people think and should be avoided.