# Is there a way to change default uppercase value of a character using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, uppercase, lowercase

I'm working on the development of a website in my native language, where the uppercase version of letter "i" is "İ". Default string.toUpperCase() method turns "i" into "I", which is a *completely* different letter (the lowercase version for this one is "ı"). Is there a way to set the default uppercase value for "i", so that I will be able to use toUpperCase() method successfully?

The locale is az_Latn_AZ.

Comment: Out of curiosity - what locale is that?

Comment: @JanneKlouman Turkish, I believe

Comment: @AriLotter thanks! Possible solution? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1850232/turkish-case-conversion-in-javascript

Comment: @JanneKlouman Azerbaijani

Comment: @MarcinPewiński This question is asking about JavaScript, not Java.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as a duplicate of the question @JanneKlouman linked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Turkish case conversion in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1850232/turkish-case-conversion-in-javascript)

Comment: toLocaleUpperCase() is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change `toUpperCase`, like this:

```
String.prototype.oldToUpperCase = String.prototype.toUpperCase;
String.prototype.toUpperCase = function() {
    return this.split("i").join("I").oldToUpperCase();
}
```

Now test it like this:

```
console.log("aaa".toUpperCase());
console.log("aiaia".toUpperCase());
```