# "İ".toLowerCase() != "i"

Tags: javascript, case-sensitive, uppercase

In Turkish, there's a letter `İ` which is the uppercase form of `i`. When I convert it to lowercase, I get a weird result. For example:

```js
var string_tr = "İ".toLowerCase();
var string_en = "i";

console.log( string_tr == string_en );  // false
console.log( string_tr.split("") );     // ["i", "̇"]
console.log( string_tr.charCodeAt(1) ); // 775
console.log( string_en.charCodeAt(0) ); // 105
```

`"İ".toLowerCase()` returns an extra character, and if I'm not mistaken, it's [COMBINING DOT ABOVE (U+0307)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0307/index.htm).

How do I get rid of this character?

I could just filter the string:

```js
var string_tr = "İ".toLowerCase();

string_tr = string_tr.split("").filter(function (item) {
    if (item.charCodeAt(0) != 775) {
        return true;
    }
}).join("");

console.log(string_tr.split(""));
```

but am I handing this correctly? Is there a more preferable way? Furthermore, why does this extra character appear in the first place?

There's some inconsistency. For example, in Turkish, there a lowercase form of `I`: `ı`. How come the following comparison returns true

```js
console.log( "ı".toUpperCase() == "i".toUpperCase() ) // true
```

while

```js
console.log( "İ".toLowerCase() == "i" ) // false
```

returns false?

Comment: Have you tried `String.toLocaleLowerCase()`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1850232/turkish-case-conversion-in-javascript

Comment: You can read more about this here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973919.aspx#stringsinnet20_topic5

Comment: @JOSEFtw I'm curious, why JS  converts `"ı".toUpperCase()` correctly, but not `"İ".toLowerCase()"`.

Comment: @akinuri, because the mapping for `ı (U+0131)` and  `i (U+0069)` are the same: `I (U+0049)`

Comment: @MinusFour Well, can't they just map `İ` to `i` instead of `i + COMBINING DOT ABOVE`? Current mapping seems a bit ridiculous.

Comment: @akinuri, it would break out some code for people that depend on that behavior. It's not that ridiculous to be honest... At any point, that's why Unicode added special casings for the turkish language. That's why you need to use `.toLocaleLowerCase`

Comment: @akinuri Turkish is specifically used as a classic example of needing to take into account locale in string comparison instead of doing a brute force `toLowerCase` - one example of an article written on it http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/turkish-i18n.html

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You’ll need a Turkish-specific case conversion, available with [`String#toLocaleLowerCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLocaleLowerCase):

```js
let s = "İ";

console.log(s.toLowerCase().length);
console.log(s.toLocaleLowerCase('tr-TR').length);
```

Comment: Wouldn't that only be useful in situations where I know the locale of the string? For example, a user inputs a string on a form, but I don't have a way of knowing the locale of the string. What should I do then? Use `.toLocaleLowerCase('tr-TR')` anyway, just to be safe? In that case, is it safe to use `.toLocaleLowerCase('tr-TR')` on every string?

Comment: @akinuri: No, it’s not safe (try lowercasing `I`). You have to know the locale of the string to transform it correctly in general. For specific situations, there might be workarounds – what’s your reason for lowercasing a string?

Comment: Currently, I have none, but in the past, I had to do this a few times. One that I can think of was storing artist names (Turkish and foreign) in a database. Using PHP, I had to map the correct chars manually.

Comment: @akinuri Your app should know what the current locale is, shouldn't be too hard to pass in.

Comment: @akinuri because [there's no way to do universal case mapping](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20030905-00/?p=42643) so you have to know which language that is. Same thing with [sorting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/locale/sorting-and-string-comparison) because the same strings may sort into [different orders](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr10/#Introduction) in different languages

Comment: @akinuri: Artist names? Would you need to lowercase those, or would a case-insensitive comparison be enough? But yeah, language is one of those exceedingly tricky problems.

Comment: @Ryan Doesn't case-insensitive comparison also require specifying the locale?

Comment: I wasn't just making comparisons back then, also creating URL friendly names. Is user's locale always trustable? Because, for example, my OS is English, though my keyboard is Turkish.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc, for case-insensitive comparison, there is a way, that is what the Invariant (or Ordinal) comparisons in .NET are: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396. Your article simply said it was difficult, it isn't actually impossible.

Comment: @NH. that doesn't solve the problem. Invariant culture is English only. What if one uses some other language and expects that "i" converts to "İ" but the culture converts it to "I"? How about the order is correct in invariant culture but not in another language? Good luck doing Turkish case comparison in invariant culture. Of course invariant culture is better when no language information is available but it's not a magic to make everyone happy. The problem is still **impossible to solve**

Comment: @Barmar: Yep, but for some situations you can cheat more reliably =D Like strings that have to be unique – you can strip out some characters in a case-folded version for the uniqueness test without ever actually displaying the mangled version of the input.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc you didn't read my comment. For case-insensitive *comparison*.

Comment: @NH. you didn't read my comment. I talked about **case-insensitive comparison**

Comment: @NH. no, it's relevant to *case comparison*. Compare `gif` and `GIF` and regardless of the result (equal or not) you'll at least make a Turkey or a non-Turkey man angry. Same with `Maße`, `MASSE` and `Masse`, would they compare the same? Ask a Swiss and a German to see. Compare [`DZ`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/01f1/index.htm) equal to `dz` will also make many people unhappy. As I said, **there's no way to make everyone happy** because there's no such thing as universal locale

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the LocalLowerCase or LocalUpperCase for languages
like Turkish and other alphabets with
dotted and dotless i versions such as Azerbaijani, Kazakh, Tatar, and Crimean Tatar.

```js
var string_tr = "İ".toLocalLowerCase();
var string_en = "i";

console.log( string_tr == string_en );  // false
console.log( string_tr.split("") );     // ["i", "̇"]
console.log( string_tr.charCodeAt(1) ); // 775
console.log( string_en.charCodeAt(0) ); // 105
```