# Return true if none of the letters in the blacklist

Tags: javascript

Return true if none of the letters in the blacklist
are present in the phrase. If at least one letter from
blacklist is present in the phrase return false;

Comparison should be case insensitive. Meaning 'A' == 'a'.

```
/**
     * 
     * @param {string} blacklist
     * @param {string} phrase
     * 
     * @returns {boolean}
     */
    function hasNoneLetters(blacklist, phrase) {
      console.log(blacklist)
      var x = phrase.includes(blacklist);
      if(x === false){
        return true
      }
      else{
        return false
      }

    }
```

Comment: I think the blacklist needs to be split into an array if it was provided as a string. The make every thing to lowercase or uppercase to compare the values. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not working because you are checking if one string is included in the other in *entirety*. Instead, you need to get each character of `blacklist` separately and check if it is present in the `phrase` string.

Also, use `toLowerCase` on the strings for case-insensitive comparison

```js
function hasNoneLetters(blacklist, phrase) {
  blacklist = blacklist.toLowerCase();
  phrase = phrase.toLowerCase();

  for (const char of blacklist)
    if (phrase.includes(char))
      return false;

  return true
}

console.log(hasNoneLetters('abc', 'This has'))
console.log(hasNoneLetters('XYZ', 'This doesnt'))
console.log(hasNoneLetters('C', 'case insensitive'))
```

---

Another option is to create a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) of the blacklisted letters. Use `Array.from` to convert the string string to an array of characters. Check if [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) of the letters are included in the set.

```js
function hasNoneLetters(blacklist, phrase) {
  const set = new Set(blacklist.toLowerCase());
  return !Array.from(phrase.toLowerCase()).some(c => set.has(c));
}
```

Comment: Thank u very match, sorry, I am nooob, this is very difficult for me ES6 understanding

Comment: Upvoted as this is the only answer so far to include case-insensitivity. However, [Turkish case conversion in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1850232/1115360) has some important information to do with that.

Comment: @JessicaBulldog I added version similar to your code

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * 
 * @param {string} blacklist
 * @param {string} phrase
 * 
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
function hasNoneLetters(blacklist, phrase) {
  console.log(blacklist)
  var phrase_parts = phrase.split(" ");
  for(var part of phrase_parts) {
    if (blacklist.includes(part)) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: It should return true if no matching letters)

Comment: fixed it. Just had to swap return values.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for every letter in the blacklist and not the full blacklist at once.

```
function hasNoneLetters(blacklist, phrase) {
  let lowerCasePhrase = phrase.toLowerCase();
  for (let letter of blacklist.toLowerCase()) {
    if (lowerCasePhrase.includes(letter)) return false
  }
  return true
}
```

Also, you might want to use a `Set` where you insert all the letters of the phrase in to optimise the performance. This will get your running time from O(N*M) down to O(max(N, M)), where N and M are the lengths of the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't asking a question - with what are you struggling?

If you're wondering why your function isn't working, `var x = phrase.includes(blacklist);`, will only return `true` if the **entire blacklist** appears, **in order**, within `phrase`.

Answer (score 0):

The shortest one answer

```
function hasNoneLetters(blacklist, phrase) {
    return !blacklist.split('').find(b => phrase.includes(b))
 }
```

```js
    function hasNoneLetters(blacklist, phrase) {
        return !blacklist.split('').find(b => phrase.includes(b))
     }

console.log(hasNoneLetters('Abc', 'the Phrase'))

console.log(hasNoneLetters('Abc', 'the PhrAse'))
console.log(hasNoneLetters('abc', 'the Phrase'))
```

Comment: Both are strings: `@param {string} blacklist @param {string} phrase`